# problem with print output to a .txt file in java

Tags: java

i write a program in netbeans, but i can not print it in a .txt file. 
indead, my programming codes do note work properly.
i think the problem is in last lines of codes.
here is my codes:

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class converttopathbased_bfs 
{

    static String START;
    static String END;
    static int numberOfNodes;
    static int numberOfArcs;
    static int numberOfCommodities;
    static int OriginDestinationOfCommodities[][] = new int[numberOfCommodities][2];
    static int neighborhoods[][] = new int[numberOfNodes][numberOfNodes];
    static int variableCosts[][] = new int[numberOfNodes][numberOfNodes];
    static int capacities[][] = new int[numberOfNodes][numberOfNodes];
    static int fixedCosts[][] = new int[numberOfNodes][numberOfNodes];
    static int demandOfCommodities[] = new int[numberOfCommodities];
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("pathBasedTest.txt");
     java.io.PrintWriter output;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.io.File data = new java.io.File("samples//test.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);

        numberOfNodes = scanner.nextInt();

        numberOfArcs = scanner.nextInt();

        numberOfCommodities = scanner.nextInt();

        Graph graph = new Graph();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArcs; i++)
        {
            int m = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            int n = scanner.nextInt() - 1;

            String S = "";
            String E = "";

            S = Integer.toString(m + 1);
            E = Integer.toString(n + 1);

            scanner.nextInt();

            scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextInt();

            graph.addEdge(S, E);

                scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextInt();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCommodities; i++)
        {            
            converttopathbased_bfs.START = scanner.next();
            converttopathbased_bfs.END = scanner.next();
            scanner.nextInt();

        LinkedList<String> visited = new LinkedList();
        visited.add(START);
        new converttopathbased_bfs().breadthFirst(graph, visited);
        }
    }

    private void breadthFirst(Graph graph, LinkedList<String> visited)  throws Exception
    {
        output = new java.io.PrintWriter (file) ;
        LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
        // examine adjacent nodes 
        for (String node : nodes)
        {
            if (visited.contains(node))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (node.equals(END))
            {
                visited.add(node);
                printPath(visited);
                visited.removeLast();
                break;
            }
        }
        // in breadth-first, recursion needs to come after visiting adjacent nodes 
        for (String node : nodes)
        {
            if (visited.contains(node) || node.equals(END))
            {
                continue;
            }
            visited.addLast(node);
            breadthFirst(graph, visited);
            visited.removeLast();
        }
    }

    private void printPath(LinkedList<String> visited) 
    {       
        for (String node : visited)
        {
            output.printf("s", node);
            output.printf(" ");
        }
        output.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

Comment: To format your code properly, select it and press CTRL+K.

Comment: What problem are you seeing?  What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are creating `output` every time `breadhtfirst` is called.  You should only create it once at the beginning of your code, and then close it at the end of your code.

You probably want for those last few lines:

```
for (String node : visited)
{
    output.printf("%s ", node);
}
output.println();
```

But we need a little more information to be sure.

You will also want to close the file at the end of your code.

```
output.close();
```

Comment: it is not working, .txt file is created but nothing is written in it.

Comment: In case you don't see it, you need to add a `%` character before the 's' in your `printf`.

Comment: i see, thanks, i put it  in the last of the "breadthFirst" method. but, all of the outputs are not written, and just the last line of string is written. i do not realy now, where should i write it?

Comment: @rahim, I would place it at the top of the main method.  That way you know it is created when you need it, and you wont have to worry about creating it again.

Comment: but output is non-static and it can not be place in static method.

Comment: @rahim, ok, I didn't see that.  You will need to make it static and initialize in in main, or initialize it above main like you did with the file.

Comment: @rahim, glad we could get it figured out.  You should consider accepting my answer so that future users will know which answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your filestream:

```
output.close()
```

Comment: i added in the last of the "breadthFirst" method, it works. but there is another problem. the output must be :

Comment: 1 2 6 7 
1 2 6 3 5 7 
1 2 6 4 7 
1 2 6 5 7 
1 3 5 7 
1 6 7 
1 6 3 5 7 
1 6 4 7 
1 6 5 7

Comment: but it just write the last line: 1657

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the following two lines:

```
output.flush();


output.close();
```

Convert it to a BufferedWriter and use the append method.

Comment: In the place when you no longer need the stream.

Comment: flush() is not necessary if you have close()

Comment: i put it in the last of the "breadthFirst" method. but, all of the outputs are not written, and just the last line of string is written. i do not realy now, where should i write it?